# how to write in <input> textbox like facebook

Tags: input, textbox

Hello to all im new and i would be grateful to be helped out from this community.

is it possible to write in  textbox suppose i write in textbox 2 words (world, universe).
what i want is that when i write WORLD & UNIVERSE after putting space or , it would select the WORLD & UNIVERSE right like we put Tags here while posting question and when i insert into database it will insert both words as 2 records not 1.

i tried  but it doesnt work i want to select like putting Tags?????

here when we put Tags it makes the word after space or ,  please if u can help in the same way and also only when i put , ...

Waiting for the kind responses.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Can we see what you have tried??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a jQuery plugin to achieve the tags functionality (I like this one http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html).

This will then allow you to post an array of your tags to the server where you can then insert them into the database as separate records.

Comment: dear Thanks alot for your help... i tried it it works fine but if i want to put 2 or more words as one like "This Is World" or "English Books" i cant put like this because when i press space it selects the word.. can u please help ????

Comment: this plugin supports spaces - take a look at the fourth example on that link

Comment: Well thanks dear .. would you please tell me how to store in the database?? his textbox is automated.. please help